# How many type of solution will this integral has?

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $\int \frac{1}{x^3 \sqrt{x^2-1}} dx$

My attempt,

Let $x=\sec u $

I ended up with the answer $\frac{1}{2} (\frac{\sqrt {x^2} \sqrt{x^{2}-1}}{x^3}+\sec^{-1} x)+c$

Comment: Any two solutions differ by a constant.  A candidate answer may be checked by differentiation.  Using that method, you can see that your answer is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Now should be okay

Comment: @GEdgar I differentiated the solution given in the problem, and I am finding that it works... The derivative of $ sec^{-1}(x) $ is $ \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} $ and the derivative of $ \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^2} $ is $ \frac{2-x^2}{x^3\sqrt{x^2 - 1}} $. Thus, the derivative of $ \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^2} + sec^{-1}(x) $ is $  \frac{2-x^2}{x^3\sqrt{x^2 - 1}} + \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} = \frac{x^2 + 2 - x ^2}{x^3\sqrt{x^2-1}} = \frac{2}{x^3\sqrt{x^2-1}} $.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have the right answer. Since this is an indefinite integral, there are infinitely many possible solutions (i.e. $ C $ is a constant that can take any value).

I would also use the same substitution as you, i.e. $ x = sec(\theta) \rightarrow dx = sec(\theta) tan(\theta) d\theta $.

$$ \int \frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx = \int \frac{1}{sec^3(\theta)} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{sec^2(\theta) - 1}} \times sec(\theta) tan(\theta) d\theta $$

Since $ sec^2(\theta) - 1 = tan^2(\theta) $, we get:

$$ \int \frac{1}{sec^3(\theta)} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{tan^2(\theta)}} \times sec(\theta) tan(\theta) d\theta = \int \frac{1}{sec^2(\theta)} d\theta = \int cos^2(\theta) d\theta $$

Since $ cos(2\theta) = 2cos^2(\theta) - 1 \rightarrow cos^2(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} (1 + cos(2\theta)) $, we get:

$$ \int cos^2(\theta) d\theta  = \int \frac{1}{2} (1 + cos(2\theta)) d\theta = \frac{1}{2} \big[ \theta + \frac{1}{2}sin(2\theta) \big] + C = \frac{1}{2} \big[ \theta + sin(\theta)cos(\theta) \big] + C $$

Finally, you want to re-write your answer in terms of $x$. To do this, recall that $ sec(\theta) = x $, so $ \theta = sec^{-1}(x)$. To find expressions for $ sin(\theta) $ and $ cos(\theta) $ in terms of $ x $, it helps to draw out a triangle, i.e.

[image: Trig Triangle]

We see that $ sin(\theta) = \frac{Opposite}{Hypothenuse} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}{x} $ and that $ cos(\theta) = \frac{Adjacent}{Hypothenuse} = \frac{1}{x} $. Putting this all together, we get:

$$ \int \frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx = \frac{1}{2} \big[ \theta + sin(\theta)cos(\theta) \big] + C = \frac{1}{2} \big[ sec^{-1}(x) + \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^2} \big] + C $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $\sqrt{x^2-1}=u\implies x^2=u^2+1$

$$\int\dfrac{x\ dx}{x^4\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\int\dfrac1{2u}\cdot\dfrac{2u}{(1+u^2)^2}$$

Now integrate by parts

Comment: Can you address the question in the title ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=cosh(u)$ and $dx=sinh(u)du$

Then 
$$\int \frac{1}{x^3 \sqrt{x^2-1}} dx  =\int \frac{sinh(u)}{cosh^3(u)sinh(u)}du= \int sech^3(u)du$$

Now you can use the reduction formula for  $\int sech^m(x)dx$